# How can I show a different url in the address bar?

Tags: html, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My webpage url is for example

```
www.animalfarm.com/animals/horses.html
```

Is it possible to show in the address bar instead:

```
horses.animalfarm.com
```

I coudn't find any tutorial or help page for this issue. I know that it is working with the text behind the .com/ (friendly URL rewriting) but I do not know if this works also with changing www to a subdomain.

I would be really happy if you could help!

Comment: Look into url masking, e.g. https://www.willmaster.com/library/web-development/url-masking.php ( URL Masking with Apache Rewrite )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any pages on your site with links you would need to change them to link to horses.animalfarm.com.

For the html file on www.animalfarm.com/animals/horses.html, you could simply redirect them using the following line in your html

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://horses.animalfarm.com/" />
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I need. The page should not really be `horses http://horses.animalfarm.com/` the page should stay at `www.animalfarm.com/animals/horses.html` Only the text in the adress bar should be displayed like `horses.animalfarm.com`. In the way friendly urls do it

Comment: You're wanting the user to go to a URL, but want their web browser to make them think they're somewhere else? No browser would let you do that as it would be a huge security problem. I.E. you could try to trick someone into thinking they're at their bank account or email account and get them to login.

Comment: hm, ok I understand. I thought maybe because it is a subdomain of my website, it is working